# R - New conditional column in data.frame from existing data not working

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to do a simple task in R by creating a column in a data frame, which will contain data of the previous column that are greater than a value. The code below gives me some (wrong) weird results.

```
set.seed(20)
x=round(runif(10),2)
y=round(runif(10),2)
df=data.frame(x=x,y=y)
df<-transform(df, w=ifelse(df$y>0.4, df$y[df$y>0.4], 0))
df
```

And the result is

```
      x    y    w
1  0.88 0.72 0.72
2  0.77 0.76 0.76
3  0.28 0.00 0.00
4  0.53 0.74 0.45
5  0.96 0.19 0.00
6  0.98 0.45 0.72
7  0.09 0.32 0.00
8  0.07 0.11 0.00
9  0.33 0.29 0.00
10 0.37 0.82 0.82
```

Any suggestions on why column `w` does not correspond to the values of the `y>0.4` and they show mixed results?

Comment: Use `ifelse(df$y > 0.4, df$y, 0)`

Comment: @DarrenTsai thank you very much. It was that simple. Greatly appreciated